# Evaluating $\int_{a}^{\infty} \tfrac{(t-a)^2}{C^2} \cdot \exp ( - \tfrac{(t-a)^2}{C^2} ) \cdot \exp(iwt) \ dt$

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_{a}^{\infty} \tfrac{(t-a)^2}{C^2} \cdot \exp ( - \tfrac{(t-a)^2}{C^2} ) \cdot \exp(iwt) \ dt$$

I thought about using the substitution $\beta \doteq \tfrac{(t-a)}{C}$ so the integral would become:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \beta^2 \cdot \exp (- \beta^2 ) \cdot \exp(i w (\beta C - a)) \ C \ d\beta$$

However, I don't know how to evaluate this either.

Any idea on how to do this?

**EDIT:** As Caran-d'Ache pointed out, I did in fact lose a minus! I'm still just learning Mathematica, how did you enter the integral?

Comment: Are you sure you have got the right integrand?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, I'm sure!

Comment: @fabian789 [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[%28b^2*E^%28b^2%29+E^%28I*O*b*C%29%29%2C+{b%2C+0%2C+Infinity}]) says that the integral does not converge. So I guess you lost minus sign in the first exponent.

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache I actually did lose one. Can you tell me the Mathematica command you used to evaluate the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one has the following integral:$$\mathrm{I}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \beta^2e^{- \beta^2} e^{i w (\beta C - a)} \ C \ d\beta$$
$$\mathrm{I}=Ce^{-i w a}\int_{0}^{\infty} \beta^2 e^{- \beta^2}   e^{i w \beta C } d\beta$$ 
Let's for simplicity set $Ce^{-i w a}=\alpha$, $w C=s$, so:
$$\mathrm{I}=\alpha\int_{0}^{\infty} \beta^2 e^{- \beta^2}   e^{i \beta s } d\beta$$
Joining the exponent terms and completing the square in the power of the resulting exponent:
$$\mathrm{I}=\alpha\int_{0}^{\infty} \beta^2 e^{- (\beta-\frac{i s}{2})^2}   e^{-\frac{s^2}{4}} d\beta$$
Again $\tilde{\alpha}=\alpha \ e^{-\frac{s^2}{4}}$ and changing the variable (and the limits of integration) from $\beta$ to $t=\beta-\frac{i s}{2}$ one can obtain:
$$\mathrm{I}=\tilde{\alpha}\int_{-\frac{i s}{2}}^{\infty-\frac{i s}{2}}\left(t+\frac{i s}{2}\right)^2 e^{- t^2}   dt$$
Expanding the terms in the brackets:
$$\mathrm{I}=\tilde{\alpha}\int_{-\frac{i s}{2}}^{\infty-\frac{i s}{2}}\left(t^2+i t s-\frac{s^2}{4}\right) e^{- t^2}=\frac{\tilde{\alpha}}{8} i \left(2 s-\sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{s^2}{4}} \left(s^2-2\right) \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)-i\right)\right)$$
where $ \text{erfi}$ - is [the imaginary error function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.1). After that one should assume all the substitutions what were made.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this seems to be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Or there is another way.
One can look at $$\mathrm{I}=\alpha\int_{0}^{\infty} \beta^2 e^{- \beta^2}   e^{i \beta s } d\beta$$ as [the Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) $\mathcal{L}_{\beta }\left[\beta ^2 e^{-\beta ^2 } \right](p)$ with $p=-is$.
One can find (from the textbooks or using Mathematica) [the answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LaplaceTransform%5Bexp%28-beta%5E2%29%2abeta%5E2,beta,%20-I%20s%5D).
And after some simplification get the same result:
$$\mathrm{I}=\frac{\tilde{\alpha}}{8} i \left(2 s-\sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{s^2}{4}} \left(s^2-2\right) \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)-i\right)\right)$$

Comment: Yes, the exercise I'm trying to solve actually asks me to Laplance transform this. I did however want to manually evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to integrate by parts twice if we have $e^{-(...)}$ instead of $e^{(...)}$, the integral in this current case does not converge

Comment: I think this would be better as a comment. If you had tried it and it worked, then it would certainly be a hint type answer. Just some friendly advice. Regards